# UITextView Scrolling inside a paging UIScrollView not working

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiscrollview, uitextview

So basically i have a UIScrollView and inside it i have a UIView as an content view the scroll view has paging set to enabled , inside the content view i have UIImage view in the top and underneath it i have a UITextView , the text view can have text larger from it's own height so it should scroll 
here is my code .

```
-(void)setUpMainScroller{     
if(MainScroller != nil)
{
    [[self.MainScrollViewContainer viewWithTag:80] removeFromSuperview] ;
}

MainScroller = [[UIScrollView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, self.view.frame.size.width, self.MainScrollViewContainer.frame.size.height)];
MainScroller.tag = 80 ;
MainScroller.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor] ;
MainScroller.showsHorizontalScrollIndicator = NO;
MainScroller.delegate = self ;
MainScroller.pagingEnabled = YES ;
MainScroller.clipsToBounds = YES;
MainScroller.delaysContentTouches = NO;
CGFloat paperWidth = MainScroller.frame.size.width;
NSDictionary * item = [elements objectAtIndex:selectedIndex] ;
NSArray * temp = item[@"Sub"] ;
NSUInteger numberOfPapers = [temp count];
count = (int)numberOfPapers ;
CGFloat por =( self.view.frame.size.width-40)/(CGFloat)numberOfPapers;
[self setupIndicatorWithPaperWidth:por andPaperCount:(int)numberOfPapers] ;


for (NSUInteger i = 0; i < numberOfPapers; i++) {
    CGFloat rest = self.MainScrollViewContainer.frame.size.height ;
    CGFloat labl =rest - 140+15 ;
    CGFloat contentheight = 140+15 + rest ;
    UIView * content = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(paperWidth*i, 0, self.view.frame.size.width, contentheight)] ;
    content.clipsToBounds = YES ;

        UIImageView * image = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(20, 0, paperWidth-40, 140)];

        image.backgroundColor = [UIColor grayColor] ;
    if(i == 0 )
        image.backgroundColor = [UIColor redColor] ;
    else if (i==1)
        image.backgroundColor = [UIColor blueColor] ;
    else if(i ==2)
        image.backgroundColor = [UIColor greenColor] ;
    CGFloat imageheight  = image.frame.size.height +15 ;
    CGFloat labelheight = contentheight - imageheight ;


    UITextView * textview= [[UITextView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake( 20 ,image.frame.origin.y + image.frame.size.height +15, paperWidth - 40 , 20)] ;
    [textview setBackgroundColor:[UIColor grayColor]] ;

    [textview setText:label.text];
    [textview setUserInteractionEnabled:YES] ;
    textview.delegate = self ;
    textview.contentSize = CGSizeMake(textview.bounds.size.width , textview.bounds.size.height+50) ;

    [content addSubview:image] ;  

    [content addSubview:@"LONG TEXT"] ;



    [MainScroller addSubview:content] ;

    //[content bringSubviewToFront:textview] ;

    [textview setScrollEnabled:YES];

          //  [MainScroller addSubview:image];


}
CGSize contentSize = CGSizeMake(paperWidth * numberOfPapers, MainScroller.bounds.size.height);
MainScroller.contentSize = contentSize;

[self.MainScrollViewContainer addSubview:MainScroller];

self.MainScrollViewContainer.scrollview =MainScroller ;
[self.MainScrollViewContainer bringSubviewToFront:MainScroller];}}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i was able to fix this by removing any container view of the main scroll view